# Fill UIImageView with other color animated

Tags: ios, swift3, core-animation

I'm having a imageview and I want that imageview to animate with a color. So my image is first a green one and then I want to animate it to a orange one.

This is my code:

```
class TestView: UIView {

    func startAnimate(){

        let size:CGSize = self.bounds.size

        let layer = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "LaunchIcon"))
        layer.frame = self.bounds

        let initialRect:CGRect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: size.height, width: size.width, height: 0)
        let finalRect:CGRect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: size.height, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        let sublayer = CALayer()
        sublayer.frame = initialRect
        sublayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        sublayer.opacity = 0.5


        let mask:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = self.bounds
        mask.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        mask.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        layer.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
        layer.layer.mask = mask

        self.layer.addSublayer(layer.layer)

        let boundsAnim:CABasicAnimation  = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
        boundsAnim.toValue = NSValue.init(cgRect:finalRect)

        let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        animationGroup.animations = [boundsAnim]
        animationGroup.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animationGroup.duration = 2
        animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

        sublayer.add(animationGroup, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

My result:

[image]

The first problem is that the orange is taking the whole frame and not just my image. The second problem is that it doesn't fill to the top.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076270/swift-color-fill-animation

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Some of the issues with your code:**

1. You add a rectangular `mask` to a layer, which is not affecting rendering at all. You never change it's frame, position, shape or anything else, so it's purpose is unclear.
2. `sublayer` is supposed to be visible inside your glass shape only, right? But in code you define it as a rectengular and it is a subview, so there is no reason it would be trimmed by the shape of your glass image.
3. Please don't call `view`s as *layer*, it's confusing for anyone who is reading your code. If it's not a layer, don't call it *layer*, simple as that.

> let layer = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "LaunchIcon"))

4. You don't need CAAnimationGroup if you're wrapping a single `CABasicAnimation`

**Working solution:**

In fact you don't need to use CoreAnimation here, you can implement this with a higher level plain `UIKit`. Your best friends in this case are **[mask](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622557-mask)** property of `UIView` and **[animateWithDuration](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622418-animate)** method:

```
class GlassView: UIView {

    let liquidView = UIView() //is going to be animated from bottom to top
    let shapeView = UIImageView() //is going to mask everything with alpha mask

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.liquidView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        self.shapeView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.shapeView.image = UIImage(named: "glass")

        self.addSubview(liquidView)
        self.mask = shapeView

        layoutIfNeeded()
        reset()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        liquidView.frame = self.bounds
        shapeView.frame = self.bounds            
    }

    func reset() {
        liquidView.frame.origin.y = bounds.height
    }

    func animate() {
        reset()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.liquidView.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[used mask](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9tzgl0ancbbihm/glass.png?dl=0)

**Implementation details:**

> The view’s alpha channel determines how much of the view’s content and
>   background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels allow the
>   underlying content to show through but fully transparent pixels block
>   that content.

Make sure your mask image is `.png` and contains a shape on a transparent background.

Comment: Great solution! it works fine with .pdf image too :)

Comment: @user1007522 I try this solution but the image is orange when I launch the app. Do you have any idea about the animation ? Thanks

Comment: @MisterFisher probably the view which is being masked (liquidView) is static in your case. Do you set/animate it’s frame anywhere?

Comment: In the viewcontroller containing the UIView called Animation, I use "let test = Animation() test.animate()" in viewDidLoad. With debugger I can see that all functions are called in Animation. What about the static notion in your answer ?

Comment: By "static" I mean that frame is probably equal to self.bounds or whatever you set there. Make sure you set a different initial value outside animation block and destination value inside animation block. I can help you if you share your code somehow.

Comment: I sent you a facebook / messenger invitation. It could be a good way to talk about my problem and send you code / printscreen. Else I ask a new question on stackoverflow but not easy to be specific or to communicate