# Changing origin point of an animation of a UIImage in Swift3

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, uiimage

I have the following code, which basically just grows a UIImage from 0 to its intended height:

```
let bounds = self.tankLevelRep.bounds

UIView.transition(with: self.tankLevelRep, duration: 2.0, animations: {self.tankLevelRep.bounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width, height: 118.0)}, completion: nil)
```

This works fine except for the fact that it grows from the middle. I would like it to grow upwards from the bottom. The attached graphic shows the animation as it nears its end. You can see that the animation is not starting from the bottom, but rather, from the center, and growing outwards. I would like for it to start at the bottom, and the image to grow upwards.

What can I change in my code to make this happen?

Notes:

• "tankLevelRep" is the outlet name for my UIImage

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should update the frame and the bounds mirror the change, in your code make sure you animate from the bottom by setting the origin to `bounds.size.height` instead of the `origin.y`. Here is a nice fill animation from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38083117/3729825).